# Set two component in a row of each arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist

I'm doing a ArrayList practice.

What I want to do is setting two things in a row.

Example

[image]

Here is what I got it work

[image]

This is my getView like

```
public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    TextView txtTitle2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
    ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon2);
    TextView extratxt2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    if(position<2){
        if(position==0){
            txtTitle.setText(itemname[0]);
            imageView.setImageResource(imgid[0]);
            extratxt.setText("95");

            txtTitle2.setText(itemname[1]);
            imageView2.setImageResource(imgid[1]);
            extratxt2.setTextColor(Color.RED );
            extratxt2.setText("116");
        }

        if(position==1){
            txtTitle.setText(itemname[2]);
            imageView.setImageResource(imgid[2]);
            extratxt.setText("94");
            txtTitle2.setText(itemname[3]);
            imageView2.setImageResource(imgid[3]);
            extratxt2.setTextColor(Color.RED );
            extratxt2.setText("121");
        }
    }
    return rowView;
};
```

MainActivity

```
ListView list;
String[] itemname ={
        "Grizzlies",
        "Suprs",
        "Rockets",
        "Warriors"
};

Integer[] imgid={
        R.drawable.mem,
        R.drawable.sas,
        R.drawable.hou,
        R.drawable.gsw
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);

    list=getListView();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

mylist.xml

[image]

There are total four lists ,I don't need the last two. 
Can I only show only two list?

I know the way is strange because I really have no idea.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: you have to redesign your holderview .That is in layout mylist.xml .

Comment: what do you mean by *Can I only show only two list?*

Comment: if you mean only two rows, control it with `getCount()`

Comment: make custom adapter and bind into recycler view.

Comment: Yes,I mean two things in a row. 
Sorry I am new to android,Could you give me some example code please

Comment: have to check my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control row count to achieve that,

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
   return 2;               // this will inflate only 2 item in your list
}
```

Replace **2** with number or length or array your desire to inflate.

Comment: Oh It works thank you.
Sorry but is there any good way to do the whole practice

Comment: You can also pass you list contain 2 elements..but this is done proper way as if you need the list  ahead your will have only 2 items in it.

Comment: So I think it is better to control list view instead of list value

Comment: Yes of course, if you could please help my another question. Thank you